# argparse multiple options combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am writing a code with argparse options as:

```
parser.add_argument("--nb", help="show number", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("--md", help="Create xyz file", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("--xsf", help="Create xsf file for md(default is xyz)"
                    , action='store_true')
```

and is called properly.

But I want, say, --xsf to work with --md option. If I use

```
./mycode.py --nb --xsf
```

It should give an error/warning that `--xsf` does not work with `--nb`, and with `--md` only

Comment: Can `md` and `nb` go together?

Comment: no. actually, as I found from the  zondo's post, `nb` and `md` is mutually exclusive group. And I want `--xsf` only as a suboption to `md`

Comment: How would you explain the alternatives to your users?  What kind of `usage` line would be clear?

Comment: what I have in mind is, -h will print  help for md, and below that, intended help for --xsf. nb will be intended at the same level of md. like,` ls --help` (-s option)

Comment: If the M-x group doesn't give you enough testing power, you may just have to do your own testing after parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a mutually-exclusive group:

```
parser.add_argument("--md", help="Create xyz file", action='store_true')

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument("--nb", help="show number", action='store_true')
group.add_argument("--xsf", help="Create xsf file for md(default is xyz)"
                    , action='store_true')
```